# Установка клиента Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle

Пытаюсь установить клиент oracle 12c 32-х разрядный на win7 64. Когда доходит до окошка где кнопка install вылетает и ничего не происходит. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Найдите папку `... \Oracle\Inventory\logs`, там должны быть файлики с логами установщика. В конце последнего лога будет сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Папки logs не нашла

Comment: Установила pl/sql developer 64 бит и смогла зайти без установки клиента. Спасибо.